# Reminders app - repeat a certain reminder

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm building a reminders app, and been really interested in how to set a reminder to repeat itself every day/every month/every hour.

Basically I want to set something to repeat, even when my app is not running. In my case a local notification fire.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the repeat interval easily using NSCalendarUnits

```
notification.repeatInterval= NSDayCalendarUnit;
```

For more calendar units check constants on http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCalendarUnit

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Local Push Notifications, because when your App is running in background this is the only way Apple would allow you to do something:

Check this for further info: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1

And this is a good tutorial about it: http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/

Answer (score 0):

Check out Apple's reference documents [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on using UILocalNotifications.  I believe that is what you're looking for.

You can utilize UILocalNotifications to show a local notification at a certain time or date, whenever you like.

David Linsin also has a good post on this [here](http://dlinsin.github.com/2011/05/18/iOSLifecycleAndUILocalNotifications.html).

Good Luck!